# Ansible: How to byapss this warning "The value 22 (type int) in a string field was converted to '22' (type string)"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have below variable declared in my defaults/main.yml

```
port: 22
```

In my play when i'm using the variable port for credentials

```
credentials:
  host: "{{ loopback_v4 }}"
  username: "user"
  ssh_keyfile: "/id_rsa"
  port: "{{port }}"
```

When i run the play i am getting below warning

```
[WARNING]: The value 22 (type int) in a string field was converted to '22' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote
the entire value to ensure it does not change.
```

I know i can get rid of this by adding a string filter like below

```
port: "{{port | string }}"
```

But i need to make changes in lot of places. So is there any other way to address this warning from the defaults/main.yml itself?

Comment: => in your data file: `port: "22"`. Ansible has a global tendency to cast a lot of its values to string and you will most probably have to wriite `{{ port | int }}" if you really need an integer somewhere. So you are not really taking any risks using the port as a string right from the beginning.

Comment: using ```port:"22"``` doesn't save me , i am still having the same warning

Comment: This value is set in `defaults/main.yml` in your role. Are you sure you did not override it somewhere else ? (your playbook, your inventory....)

Comment: yes. i am just using it by ``` port: "{{port }}" ``` all over